# Playwright: Cannot find module

Tags: typescript, playwright, web-testing

I have a class 'Button' and I'm trying to import it into my example.spec.ts file.
I don't get any error from the compiler, but when I run the test, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/.../automation/controls/Button' imported from /Users/.../automation/tests/example.spec.ts
```

File structure is:

```
controls
   |
    -> Button.ts
tests
   |
    -> example.spec.ts
```

Button.ts

```
class Button extends BaseElement{}
```

exapmle.spec.ts

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import Button from "../controls/Button";

test('Test Base Elements', async ({ page }) => {

  const btnLocator: string = '[automation-id=next-button]';
  const continueButton = new Button(page, btnLocator, 'Continue Button');
});
```

I'm using Playwright 1.25.2

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to Page interface in playwright.
You have to make changes to the import in your class (in my case in Button class)
Add `import type` and `.js` to your custom class.
Should look like this:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import Button from "../controls/Button.js";

test('Test Base Elements', async ({ page }) => {

  const btnLocator: string = '[automation-id=next-button]';
  const continueButton = new Button(page, btnLocator, 'Continue Button');
});
```

And the import of the {Page} like this:

```
import type { Page } from "@playwright/test";
```

Comment: That won't work if you're trying to import a TS file.